# Failed PostgreSQL database connection in Pentaho Data Integration PDI

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, etl, pentaho

Objective: Set up a connection with PostgreSQL db in PDI. I'm a noob in all this stuff, so each step forward requires long resolution time.

I'm trying to set up the connection to a PostgreSQL database in order to prepare some queries for an ETL process in PDI. But there's no way to succeed with the connection.

I've tried with PostgreSQL connection type and with Generic database connection type and the error is always related with the drivers.

The version of the PostgreSQL db I'm trying to connect is 9.5.25 and I'm working in Ubuntu 20.04 and Java 8 as demands Pentaho Data Integration.

Below the error message after failed connection:

"Connection failed. Verify all connection parameters and confirm that the appropriate driver is installed. Connection to [IP]:[Port] refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections."

I am literally in despair, don't know what I'm doing wrong. Will be very grateful with anyone who can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the jdbc driver to connect to postgresql DB in the **pdi-installation/lib** directory, you just put the *.jar file there and restart spoon to have the library available.

That driver can be downloaded from postgresql downloads. The Community Edition of PDI only comes with a small number of jdbc drivers, for each type of database you need to connect to, you should check if the jdbc driver is available in that directory, and if it's up to date or if you need a more recent version of the driver.

This is a link for the official Pentaho documentation, looking for information in Hitachi Vantara documentation is becoming more and more difficult, they don't always clarify what steps apply only for the Enterprise Edition and are not available for the Community Edition: https://help.hitachivantara.com/Documentation/Pentaho/9.2/Setup/JDBC_Drivers_Reference

Comment: Thank you so much Ana, that's the main problem, for this db version I don't know which driver should I use. I've downloaded all the drivers available from the official site, but the issue persists.

Comment: Normally, if you aren't using very old or very recent versions of the database, the driver version isn't very important, so probably it isn't a problem about the driver version, but about connection to the database. Have you verified that you can connect to the database in the same machine but using another program? Maybe it is a problem about credentials (correct user/pwd machine:port:db) or about additional security restrictions to connect to the db (your ip is authorised, SSL security measures or something like that)